# Is there a way to get permanent link ids directly in HERE traffic flow result?

Tags: here-api

I want to use traffic flow data to enhance a route with traffic information like the jam factor.

The recommended way seems to get a route, download TMC tiles for all functional classes and areas of the route, and match the route links to the TMC codes in the traffic flow data, e.g. see [How to use HERE Maps to develop custom routing algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844477/how-to-use-here-maps-to-develop-custom-routing-algorithms) .

However, the traffic flow documentation (TrafficML_RealTime_Specification_v3.2.2.docx) mentions a tag "SHP/LID" in the Flow Item Description to contain the link id, which could simplify the whole process:

```
SHP/LID:
LinkID associated with the SHP reference. The linkID will be in
driving direction order; “F” represents travel direction FROM
reference node, “T” represents travel direction TO reference
node (For example, 123456789T or 987654321F).
```

In my API call I explicitly request shapes (responseattributes=sh) and receive them, but there is no "LID" field given.

https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.2/flow.json?corridor=52.5396895,12.9778897;52.5394964,12.9782331;52.5390244,12.9769778;52.539078,12.976774;52.5392067,12.9762483;52.5395072,12.9750788;52.5396144,12.974714;52.5397754,12.974124;52.5400114,12.9732764;52.5405693,12.9723108;52.5409126,12.9719353;52.5415349,12.97068;52.5416744,12.9694784;52.5404727,12.9654121;52.5387347,12.9640496;52.5384343,12.9646397;52.5380695,12.9651332;52.5379193,12.965219;52.5370181,12.9656482;52.5359452,12.9659379;52.5349581,12.9661417;52.5339067,12.9663348;1000&responseattributes=sh,fc&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy

```
{
  "RWS": [
    {
      "RW": [
        {
          "FIS": [
            {
              "FI": [
                {
                  "TMC": {
                    "PC": 10213,
                    "DE": "Berlin-Spandau",
                    "QD": "+",
                    "LE": 4.18578
                  },
                  "SHP": [
                    {
                      "value": [
                        "52.55838,12.96583 52.55761,12.96545 52.55705,12.9652 52.55641,12.96494 52.55588,12.96473 52.55577,12.96468 "
                      ],
                      "FC": 1
                    },
                    {
                      "value": [
                        "52.55577,12.96468 52.55566,12.96464 "
                      ],
                      "FC": 1
                    },
...
                    {
                      "value": [
                        "52.55935,12.96635 52.55838,12.96583 "
                      ],
                      "FC": 1
                    }
                  ],
                  "CF": [
                    {
                      "TY": "TR",
                      "SP": 120,
                      "SU": 121.78,
                      "FF": 105,
                      "JF": 0,
                      "CN": 0.99
                    }
                  ]
                },
```

Is there a way to receive permanent ids with the flow data?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question and solutions.

Please have a look at below.

[Why does not the TMC from traffic data match with the TMC from PDE layers LINK_TMC_FC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882091/why-does-not-the-tmc-from-traffic-data-match-with-the-tmc-from-pde-layers-link-t)

Comment: Thanks. The linked answer is helpful to implement a solution with TMC layers, but I was specifically asking whether it's possible to skip that step and have the link id directly in the traffic flow response.